# Resizing images on Google Colab using Python Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory, image-resizing

I've my ipynb and a folder named PRimage (with 100+ images) in my google drive and my drive is already mounted at /content/drive. My images are arranged in sequence eg. 1_1.jpg, 1_2.jpg and so on. I'm trying to use a for loop to resize all images, like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from os import listdir
from matplotlib import image
from PIL import Image

loaded_images = list()
for filename in listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/PRimage'):
  img_data = image.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/PRimage/'+ filename)
  loaded_images.append(img_data)
  print('> loaded %s %s' % (filename, img_data.shape))

def resize():
    files = listdir('/content/drive/My Drive/PRimage')
    for item in files:
            image = Image.open(item)
            image.thumbnail((64,64))
            print(image.size)

resize()
```

However, I get this error message:

[image]

Comment: Write the text of the source code and the error, rather than posting an image of them.

Comment: Why are you listing the directory contents twice?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The first time is for testing purpose. I successfully loaded those images. But when I tried to build a for loop to resize those image, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a new code cell and use `pwd` to check your **present working directory**. Make sure it is at `/content/drive/My Drive/PRimage`. Use `cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/PRimage` to change dirs. Your `FileNotFoundError` is the cause of your unknown pwd. Always look for your root working dirs in such cases. Your code executes from pwd and expects the similar dir structure within it.

#### Helper function to resize image

```
def resize_image(src_img, size=(64,64), bg_color="white"): 
    from PIL import Image

    # rescale the image so the longest edge is the right size
    src_img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Create a new image of the right shape
    new_image = Image.new("RGB", size, bg_color)

    # Paste the rescaled image onto the new centered background
    new_image.paste(src_img, (int((size[0] - src_img.size[0]) / 2), int((size[1] - src_img.size[1]) / 2)))

    # return the resized image
    return new_image


# get the list of test image files
test_folder = '/content/drive/My Drive/PRimage'
test_image_files = os.listdir(test_folder)

# Empty array on which to store the images
image_arrays = []
size = (64,64)
background_color="white"

# Get the images
for file_idx in range(len(test_image_files)):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(test_folder, test_image_files[file_idx]))

    # resize the image
    resized_img = np.array(resize_image(img, size, background_color))

    # Add the image to the array of images
    image_arrays.append(resized_img)
```